# Tricky vertical align center with css

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment, fixed-width

I found different suggestions on how to vertically align stuff using css. However, none of those could handle what I wanted. Here is what I want:

In general I have some text that should fill the left half of some space and a picture that should be in the right half of the space.

If the height of the text is smaller than the picture both text and picture should vertically align at top of the space:

```
TextTextText   PicturePicture
TextTextText   PicturePicture
               PicturePicture
```

If the height of the text is greater than the height of the picture, then the the text should vertically align on top and the picture at the middle relative to the text.

```
TextTextText
TextTextText   PicturePicture
TextTextText   PicturePicture
TextTextText   PicturePicture
TextTextText
```

Here is one straight forward way I tried (text-version without picture):

```
<div style="width: 100%">
  <div style="width: 50%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
    TextTextText <br>
    TextTextText <br>
    TextTextText
  </div><div style="width: 50%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
    PicturePicture <br>
    PicturePicture
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the effect I intended was not achieved. The right inner div (Picture) is just aligned on top rather than in the middle relative to the text. There is no difference between setting `vertical-align: middle` and `vertical-align: top`. However, interestingly setting `vertical-align: bottom` makes a difference.

The outer div is contained in some other element of a certain width. However, I cannot specify this width by any fixed measure, e.g. px. Same for the two inner divs with equal width.

Making the inner divs table cells achieved the right vertical effect. However, I cannot use `display: table-cell`, since I need to make sure that the left inner div maintains its width even though the right inner div could have content that overflows to the right, like `PicturePicturePicturePicturePicture...`. This would lead to shrinking the width of the left cell, which I don't want.

Furthermore, I do not know the height of the content, so none of the tricks for vertical alignment that use a fixed height works.

It seemed not an too uncommon task, but I was unable to find any solution. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Do you know the height of the picture?

Comment: No, I don't know the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what behaviour you want when the picture is too wide for the right inner div, other than it should not affect the width of the left inner div, but does this meet your requirements?

HTML.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="caption cell">
    Text Text Text <br/>
    Text Text Text <br/>
    Text Text Text <br/>
    Text Text Text <br/>
    Text Text Text <br/>
    Text Text Text
  </div>

  <div class="picture cell">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x50" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {display:table; table-layout: fixed; width:100%; }
.cell { display: table-cell; width:50%; }
.caption { vertical-align: top; }
.picture { vertical-align: middle; }
.picture div { overflow-x:hidden; }
```

JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/92wcy/1/

Comment: Great! This solution seems to work perfectly. So the important thing was the `table-layout: fixed`. (I removed the div with the hidden overflow, since it is all right for me if it is visible.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the left column to shrink then add a `min-width` to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/pUbWt/1/

```
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .caption, .container .picture {
  display: table-cell;
}

.container .caption {
  vertical-align: top;
  min-width: 10em;
}

.container .picture {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Flexbox would also work, but its a little early to start using in production sites.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it is not possible to achieve my desired effect by setting `min-width: 50%`. It still shrinks. But maybe I can (and have to) live with a fixed with?

Comment: A flexbox solution would look like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/pUbWt/4/ (prefixes not included).  The inline-block on the child elements is there purely for browsers without flexbox support.  It will look perfect in capable browsers, passable in incapable browsers.

Comment: Thanks again. The flexbox solution does not seem to work properly (in Chrome 24 and FF 18). Does not align in the middle vertically and furthermore the picture goes underneath the text when too wide (more than 50% width). So even such a new concept seems incapable. That is surprising.

Comment: Chrome requires prefixes, FF20 is the earliest you can get modern flexbox support and will be prefix free.  The wrap is optional:  http://jsfiddle.net/pUbWt/6/

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment is always tricky as CSS wasn't made to accomplish that.
Still, is this what you were after? http://jsfiddle.net/N7px2/

*If so, read on.*
First, I removed your inline styles as this is bad practice. Simply use `<style>...</style>` in the head of your HTML, or even better: Use an external CSS file.

Then, I floated your divs `#b` and `#c` to align them like in your example. See the `background-color` and `border` to get a quick idea where each element is placed.
Because floats let the parent element collapse, I used a clearfix to fix that. Read more about that [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Now the vertical alignment: I positioned the image in `#c` absolute and gave it a margin `top: 50%`. Obviously that pushed the image too much, but that's how it works. After that, I applied a negative `margin-top: -25%` to pull the image back in place. Please take note that this only works if the parent element is relative positioned.
The browser support for negative margins is really good and as long they aren't used to fix a bad layout it's alright to use them.

And another note: Because `position: absolute` takes an element out of the flow, `#c` collapses. If you wanted to give `#c` a `background-image` or something similar, you need a bit more markup to fix that - simply add another div.

Hope that helped you in any way!

Edit: Sorry, I just realised that this code isn't exactly what you were after I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But the picture not really in the middle. In Firefox it is so much up that it is almost invisible - just a small gray line remains. Chrome is better, but there it is a little bit too much up. I don't know why...